Removing Section of Beam Over Column
I need to run an HVAC duct through a flush mounted beam and I have very few options to do it.... So, I have a beam consisting of a triple 2x10 w/ 2x4 ledgers running continuously over a masonry column which is supporting it. If the column is approximately 16" wide and I need at least 3" of bearing for each side of the beam (4x more than required by calc), would it be possible to completely remove up to 10" of the middle over the column? This opening would allow me to run my ductwork through that opening. Load on this column is only approx 100 sq ft of residential flooring...not much.
While it seems a little odd, I cannot see anything wrong with this idea. There are no significant lateral forces, but the floor provides some support in that direction.
Thoughts?

this sounds like a terrible idea, but your description isn't enough.

and you are going to trust a anonymous person here

Your idea should be presented to a structural engineer.  If they determine it is feasible, go for it.

Does the masonry column have support underneath it?  Either a real footing or support structure.  Would think a masonry column will be structural, but might only be a design/cosmetic feature also.

This sounds like it's in the basement. Why can't the ductwork go around the column?
